# How does templates and React work?

Tags: reactjs, templates

I'm new to React, and I'm using the Nifty template, which is some htmls, css and javascripts. My main problem is that the nifty.js has some binding functions, for examples, it bind onClick events to make some animations.

I import the nifty.js in my index.html. But of what I know about React, the html is added dynamically so when the nifty.js runs, the html doesn't exists yet. That's a problem because it doesn't binds the events to the html.

My question is, how does React and normal templates work. Is there a way (besides adding a call on onComponentDidUpdate ) to run the scripts of template?

Do I have to find a more compatible template? Are templates specifically build for react?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using a UI library (in this case React) compatible CSS framework. My suggestion would be http://www.material-ui.com.

Aside from that, you'd waste more time than necessary to have it work with some non-compatible library.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
<html>
  <head>...</head>
  <body>
    <div id="#reactAppId"></div>
    <script src="nifty.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because in React html is added dynamically, so when the page is rendered the nifty.js scripts has already run and thus the binds are not done, because the HTML doesn't exists. Or do I have my facts wrong?